# Does the VS2008 Report Viewer support radio buttons or checkboxes?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reportviewer, checkbox

Does the Visual Studio 2008 Report Viewer (for a Winform) support adding checkboxes or radio buttons?  Currently I am trying to create a report (via wizard or manually) based on a MySQL based dataset.  It appears that all fields all treated as textboxes even though I would like to have some checkboxes to represent true/false (tinyint) field values.

UPDATE1:

I have provided details on how the solution worked on my [blog](http://butastrangerhere.blogspot.com/2010/11/adding-checkbox-to-report-in-visual.html).

Comment: @Hans - can you change your comment to an answer?  Your suggestion set me on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no checkbox control available in the toolbox.  You could try an Image with a screenshot of a checkbox.  Bind its Visibility.ToggleItem property, I think.